# Printing floating point numbers from x86-64 seems to require %rbp to be saved

Tags: assembly, floating-point, x86-64

When I write a simple assembly language program, linked with the C library, using gcc 4.6.1 on Ubuntu, and I try to print an integer, it works fine:

```
        .global main
        .text
main:
        mov     $format, %rdi
        mov     $5, %rsi
        mov     $0, %rax
        call    printf
        ret
format:
        .asciz  "%10d\n"
```

This prints 5, as expected.

But now if I make a small change, and try to print a floating point value:

```
        .global main
        .text
main:
        mov     $format, %rdi
        movsd   x, %xmm0
        mov     $1, %rax
        call    printf
        ret
format:
        .asciz  "%10.4f\n"
x:
        .double 15.5
```

This program seg faults *without printing anything*.  Just a sad segfault.

But I can fix this by pushing and popping `%rbp`.

```
        .global main
        .text
main:
        push    %rbp
        mov     $format, %rdi
        movsd   x, %xmm0
        mov     $1, %rax
        call    printf
        pop     %rbp
        ret
format:
        .asciz  "%10.4f\n"
x:
        .double 15.5
```

Now it works, and prints 15.5000.

My question is: why did pushing and popping `%rbp` make the application work?  According to the ABI, `%rbp` is one of the registers that the callee *must* preserve, and so `printf` cannot be messing it up.  In fact, `printf` worked in the first program, when only an integer was passed to `printf`.  So the problem must be elsewhere?

Comment: Out of interest, what's the purpose of that `mov` into `%rax`?

Comment: Count of floating point arguments, IIRC.

Comment: Related: you can't directly print a `float` with `printf`, only `double` (with `"%f"`) or `long double` because of C promotion rules for variadic functions: [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784).

Comment: Also related; glibc `printf` only cares about stack alignment when `%al != 0`, because that's how gcc compiles variadic functions that might accept FP args.  [printf float in nasm assembly 64-bit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20594800) shows that `printf` happens to not crash when called with a misaligned stack and RAX=0, and the answer shows gcc's code (which runs only for non-zero AL) that dumps xmm0..7 to the stack with `movaps` (variadic functions can accept `__m128` args, too, not just `double`.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I suspect the problem doesn't have anything to do with `%rbp`, but rather has to do with stack alignment. To quote the ABI:

> The ABI requires that stack frames be aligned on 16-byte boundaries. Speciﬁcally, the end of
>   the argument area (%rbp+16) must be a multiple of 16. This requirement means that the frame
>   size should be padded out to a multiple of 16 bytes.

The stack is aligned when you enter `main()`. Calling `printf()` pushes the return address onto the stack, moving the stack pointer by 8 bytes. You restore the alignment by pushing another eight bytes onto the stack (which happen to be `%rbp` but could just as easily be something else).

Here is the code that `gcc` generates (also [on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0Aint+main(void)+%7B%0A++++printf(%22%2510.4f%5Cn%22,+1.234)%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g464,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu99+-Wall+-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+4.6.4+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)):

```
.LC1:
        .ascii "%10.4f\12\0"
main:
        leaq    .LC1(%rip), %rdi   # format string address
        subq    $8, %rsp           ### align the stack by 16 before a CALL
        movl    $1, %eax           ### 1 FP arg being passed in a register to a variadic function
        movsd   .LC0(%rip), %xmm0  # load the double itself
        call    printf
        xorl    %eax, %eax         # return 0 from main
        addq    $8, %rsp
        ret
```

As you can see, it deals with the alignment requirements by subtracting 8 from `%rsp` at the start, and adding it back at the end.

You could instead do a dummy push/pop of whatever register you like instead of manipulating `%rsp` directly; [some compilers do use a dummy push to align the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37773787/why-does-this-function-push-rax-to-the-stack-as-the-first-operation) because [this can actually be cheaper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36631576/what-is-the-stack-engine-in-the-sandybridge-microarchitecture) on modern CPUs, and saves code size.

Comment: I think you're right - I've run into similar problems myself.  The reason it works for an integer is just luck of the draw.  Undefined behaviour and all that.  OP's first example doesn't work on my machine without a stack adjustment, either.  I just used `sub $8, %rsp`, though.

Comment: Sometimes the number of pushes done may depend, so the stack may be aligned to 16 bytes or not. A logical AND for `sp` or `spl` works always, like this: `and spl,0xf0`.

Comment: @NPE Nice answer.  I was hoping it was something like that.  I got the `%push rbp` idea from writing the code in C and doing `gcc -S`.  I know the 32-bit assembly `push %ebp; mov %esp, %ebp` stack-frames very well, and figured gcc's pushing of `%rbp` was a relic of those old days and would have been shocked if it actually mattered.  Thanks for the note about the alignment; I will go back and study the ABI docs much more carefully!

Comment: Is that exact gcc output for some platform?  Normally you get `.LC1` (with a leading dot, so it's a GAS local label), and Linux ELF systems don't use leading underscores.  Is that from MacOS X, which uses the x86-64 SysV calling convention and `_` on symbol names?  It'd probably be better to match the OP's code for Ubuntu, so it doesn't look like `_main` instead of `main` is a correction / part of the answer.  e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/2PKKAP has the output from gcc4.6.4 `-O3`, and uses `.LC...` and no `_`, but is otherwise identical to your answer except for instruction order.