# printf float in nasm assembly 64-bit

Tags: assembly, printf, nasm, x86-64, calling-convention

I want to print a float value with printf

```
global main
extern printf

section .data
   string: db `%f\n`, 0

section .bss
   rs: resq 1

[...]

   movq xmm0, [rs]
   mov rdi, string
   mov rax, 0
   call printf
```

rs contains the floating value 1.6

```
(gdb) x/fg &rs
0x600ad8 <rs>:  1.6000000000000001
```

but the program prints

```
[username@localhost folder]$ ./programname
0.000000
```

who can I get the program to print 1.6? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: The alignment issue is a duplicate of [Printing floating point numbers from x86-64 seems to require %rbp to be saved](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16097173), but the first part (about AL = number of FP args in registers) is not.

Answer (score 8):

The first problem is your code setting `AL` (via `RAX`) to `0` whereas it must be `1` because you pass a floating point argument (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6212835/249230) for details). Basically `AL` should contain the number of variable arguments passed in `xmmN` registers.

Fixing that without other changes would result in a segfault inside `printf`, [caused by stack misalignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097173/printing-floating-point-numbers-from-x86-64-seems-to-require-rbp-to-be-saved). The program crashes at a `movaps` instruction (which expects the memory operand to be aligned on 16-byte boundary):

```
=> 0x7ffff7a65f84 <__printf+36>:    movaps %xmm0,0x50(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7a65f89 <__printf+41>:    movaps %xmm1,0x60(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7a65f8e <__printf+46>:    movaps %xmm2,0x70(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7a65f93 <__printf+51>:    movaps %xmm3,0x80(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7a65f9b <__printf+59>:    movaps %xmm4,0x90(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7a65fa3 <__printf+67>:    movaps %xmm5,0xa0(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7a65fab <__printf+75>:    movaps %xmm6,0xb0(%rsp)
   0x7ffff7a65fb3 <__printf+83>:    movaps %xmm7,0xc0(%rsp)
```

When entering `main` (or any other function), the stack is aligned RSP%16 == 8, but you need RSP%16 == 0 before a `call`.  If you fix this the program works fine. Below is my test program (notice the `sub rsp, 8` in the beginning):

```
global main
default rel     ; use a more efficient [rel foo] addressing mode by default
extern printf

section .data
    string db `%f\n`, 0
    rs dq 1.6

section .text

main:
    sub  rsp, 8                ; align the stack

    movsd xmm0, qword [rs]     ; load a Scalar Double
    mov  rdi, string           ; 64-bit absolute address of format string
    mov  eax, 1                ; AL=1  number of FP args in XMM regs
    call printf

    add  rsp, 8
    xor  eax, eax           ; return 0
    ret                     ; or  call exit with EDI=0,  not call _exit or syscall
; don't use _exit() after printf, it won't flush stdio buffers.
; which will be non-empty if output stdout is redirected to a file.
;       mov eax, 60         ; __NR_exit from unistd_64.h
;       xor edi, edi
;       syscall
```

Possible pitfalls and related Q&As:

- *[Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38379553/using-printf-in-assembly-leads-to-empty-output-when-piping-but-works-on-the-ter)* - Don't mix `printf` with raw `_exit()` system calls.
- *[How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register)* - for more efficient ways to put the format-string address into RDI
- For maintaining 16-byte stack alignment, see: *[glibc scanf Segmentation faults when called from a function that doesn't align RSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51070716/glibc-scanf-segmentation-faults-when-called-from-a-function-that-doesnt-align-r)*
- *[Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux from assembly (yasm) code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52126328/cant-call-c-standard-library-function-on-64-bit-linux-from-assembly-yasm-code)* - if your linker won't insert a PLT stub for `call printf`, e.g. in a PIE executable.

Comment: I've changed the code, but now it crash with a seg fault in printf.

Comment: You should `ret` from `main` if you're using stdio functions.  `sys_exit` doesn't flush buffers, so you'll lose the output if you pipe this program into something else (so stdio will make stdout full-buffered instead of line buffered).  Also, `movsd` is the most idiomatic instruction for loading a scalar `double`.

Comment: 0x60 isn't a sys_exit, 0x3c is. I think you meant to use a decimal 60.

Answer (score 1):

> what am I doing wrong?

**First**: make sure you are using the right calling convention (stack, registers, left to right, right to left, etc.). If your program indeed prints a floating point number, although it is not the one you required, then at least the format string is being passed correctly (or you are having a lot of luck and `printf` found the address of the format string at the right place even if you didn't put its address there).

**Second**: the number you are trying to print... is it a float or a double? `rs` is defined to hold a quadword value (64 bits), but floats are 32 bits. So, if the first point has been checked and it's ok, I suggest you to use `"%lf"` as format, instead of `"%f"`.

BTW: why do you put `RAX = 0`? What does it mean regarding the call to `printf`?

UPDATE: This may help you. A disassembly of a silly program (`f.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  float x;

  x = 1.6;
  printf ("%f\n", x);
}
```

`$ gcc -c -S f.c`

`$ less f.s`

```
        .file   "f.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC1:
        .string "%f\n"
        .text
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $0x3fcccccd, %eax
        movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
        movss   -4(%rbp), %xmm0
        cvtps2pd        %xmm0, %xmm0
        movl    $.LC1, %eax
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        movl    $1, %eax
        call    printf
        leave
```

Comment: rax actually al should hold the number of xmm registers used, I changed it to one but now the program crashes with a seg fault in printf. the floating arguments of printf are stored in the xmm registers (amd64 assembler), the string address is stored in rdi.

Comment: the strange thing is that when i put a 1 into rax printf crashes with a seg fault and when i put 0 into rax it prints 0.000, because rax is the float argument count

Comment: `%f` for printf wants a `double` because of C's type promotion rules.  `%lf` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
; file: pf.asm
; assemble with:  nasm -f elf64 pf.asm -o pf.o
; link with: ld -pie -z noexecstack -e _start -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o pf pf.o -lc

default rel             ; Use PC relative offsets (for PIE executable)

global _start           ; Execute at _start (don't use any provided startup code)

extern printf           ; printf is our only external function

section .rodata         ; The format string in printf should be read only
    string: db "Your number is %f", 0xa, 0

section .data           ; We could make this read only, but if we want to change it
    rs dq 1.6           ; through a scanf or something we can

section .text           ; Program code

_start:
;    Uncomment stack frame stuff if stack space needed, not needed for this example

;    push rbp           ; Setup our stack frame
;    mov rbp, rsp

;    sub rsp, 8         ; Create space on the stack

    movq xmm0, qword [rs]       ; Put float in xmm0
    lea rdi, [string]   ; Load address of string, lea is needed for PC relative
    mov eax, 1          ; Using floating point numbers, 0 extend into rax
    call printf wrt ..plt  ; PC relative function call

;    add rsp, 8         ; Remove allocated space on the stack

;    pop rbp            ; Undo our stack frame 

    mov eax, 60         ; Exit syscall
    xor edi, edi        ; No error, 0 extend into rdi
    syscall
```

Comment: This is correct and a good example, except for some of the comments being potentially misleading.  You don't need `push rbp` in `_start`; there is no caller with a value to save.  You could do a `push 0` to give backtracing an end point.  Your code would work with the stack stuff uncommented, but the comments don't explain the need to maintain 16-byte stack alignment (see my edit to szx's answer), or the fact that `_start` is special: it's not a function.  At `_start`, RSP%16 == 0, same as you need before a `call`.  In functions, like `main`, RSP%16 == 8 on entry.

Comment: `mov eax, 1` does zero-extend into RAX, but that's irrelevant: the register that variadic functions look at to figure out if they should dump the XMM regs is just `AL`.  `mov eax,1` is sometimes more efficient than `mov al,1`, but takes more code size.  For `xor edi,edi`, again zero-extension is irrelevant: the syscall signature is `_exit(int)`, so it only looks at the low 32 bits of the register.  (https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/exit.2.html).

Comment: Also, don't use a raw `_exit` system call after printf: *[Using printf in assembly leads to empty output when piping, but works on the terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38379553)* - use `call exit` also from libc, which will flush stdio, necessary if you redirect to a file like `./test > number.txt` - your program won't `write` anything when stdout isn't a TTY.  (`strace ./text > number.txt`)

Comment: `call printf wrt ..plt` isn't a PC-relative call directly to printf.  `call foo` is always PC-relative, using `call rel32`.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/call.  `call printf wrt ..plt` calls through a PLT stub, the Procedure Linking Table.  `ld` doesn't do this for you when making a PIE executable, unlike when linking a traditional executable where it will invent a PLT stub and rewrite `call printf` to reference the PLT entry. [Can't call C standard library function on 64-bit Linux](//stackoverflow.com/q/52126328) .  So your code is correct, comment isn't; maybe say "PIE function call"