# ASM x64 scanf printf double, GAS

Tags: c, assembly, printf, 64-bit, scanf

I can't figure out why this code isn't working for me. I need to use scanf function for double and then printf for same double.
When using this code results are not good. What I see are pretty random characters.

```
.data

d1: .double


format: .asciz "%lf\n"
format2: .asciz "%lf"

.text
.globl main

main:

subq $8, %rsp

#scanf 
movq $0, %rax
movq $d1, %rsi
movq $format2, %rdi
call scanf
addq $16, %rsp

#printf 
movq $1, %rax
movsd d1, %xmm0
movq $format, %rdi
call printf     
addq $16, %rsp

#exit
movq $1, %rdi
xorq %rax, %rax
call exit
```

Comment: Debugger, step through, watch register values.

Comment: This probably isn't the problem, since `main` never returns and you never read any stack memory, but you're breaking the stack with your `add $16, %rsp` after each `call`.  `%rsp` is a call-preserved register, so it has the same value after the call as it did before.  Also, you should put `d1` in the bss, not `.data`, because you don't need to store a value for it in your executable.  Actually it is the problem.

Comment: ^^ lol,  panto comment: 'Oh no it isn't'....'Oh yes it is'

Comment: @MartinJames: yup, I was curious what the hell `.double` with no argument would assemble to, so I assembled this code and checked `readelf -a` output.  Turns out `d1` had the same address as `format`...  Then found 15 minutes worth of other stuff to type after a last-minute comment edit.

Comment: [Another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39356236/why-does-x86-program-segfault-without-data-section) for the same issue with different symptoms.  (`.int` with an empty list leads to no BSS being created at all, leading to a segfault.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
.data
d1: .double     # declares zero doubles, since you used an empty list
format: .asciz "%lf\n"
```

`d1` and `format` have the same address, since `.double` with no args assembles to nothing.  ("[`.double` expects zero or more flonums, separated by commas.  It assembles floating point numbers.](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Double.html)").

So `scanf` overwrites the format string you use for `printf`.  This is the random garbage that `printf` prints.

The fix is to actually reserve some space, preferably on the stack.  But if you really want static storage then use the BSS.  ([This doc explains it well](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/gnuasm.html#SEC44), even though it's about some specific gcc port.)

Instead, use this:

```
#.bss
# .p2align 3
# d1: .skip 8           ### This is the bugfix.  The rest is just improvements

# or just use .lcomm instead of switching to the .bss and back
.lcomm d1, 8

.section .rodata
print_format: .asciz "%f\n"     # For printf, "%f" is the format for double.   %lf still works to print a double, though.  Only %llf or %Lf is long double.
scan_format:  .asciz "%lf"      # scanf does care about the trailing whitespace in the format string: it won't return until it sees something after the whitespeace :/  Otherwise we could use the same format string for both.

.text
.globl main
main:
    subq $8, %rsp

    xor  %eax,%eax
    mov  $d1, %esi            # addresses for code and static data are always in the low 2G in the default "small" code model, so we can save insn bytes by avoiding REX prefixes.
    mov  $scan_format, %edi
    call scanf

    mov   $1, %eax
    movsd d1, %xmm0
    mov   $print_format, %edi
    call  printf

    add   $8, %rsp
    ret

    #xor  %edi,%edi   # exit(0) means success, but we can just return from main instead.  It's not a varargs function, so you don't need to zero rax
    #call exit
```

For more stuff about writing efficient asm code, see the links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

---

Also would have worked, but wasted 8 bytes in your executable:

```
.data
d1: .double 0.0
```

---

**Or to use scratch space on the stack**.  Also changed: RIP-relative LEA for the format strings, so this will work in a PIE (PIC executable).  The explicit `@plt` is necessary to generate PLT when making a PIE executable.

```
.globl main
main:
    xor  %eax, %eax          # no FP args.  (double* is a pointer, aka integer)
    push %rax                # reserve 8 bytes, and align the stack.  (sub works, push is more compact and usually not slower)

    mov  %rsp, %rsi          # pointer to the 8 bytes
    lea  scan_format(%rip), %rdi
    call scanf@plt
    # %eax will be 1 if scanf successfully converted an arg

    movsd (%rsp), %xmm0
    mov   $1, %eax           # 1 FP arg in xmm registers (as opposed to memory)
    lea   print_format(%rip), %rdi

    pop   %rdx               # deallocate 8 bytes.  add $8, %rsp would work, too
    jmp  printf@plt          # tailcall  return printf(...)

.section .rodata
print_format: .asciz "%f\n"
scan_format:  .asciz "%lf"
```

You could even store your format strings as immediates, too, but then you need to reserve more stack space to keep it aligned.  (e.g. `push $"%lf"`, except GAS syntax doesn't do multi-character integer constants.  In NASM you really could do `push '%lf'` to get those 3 bytes + 5 zeros of padding.)

Related: [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37082784/how-to-print-a-single-precision-float-with-printf): you can't because of C default-conversion rules that promote to `double`.

Also related: a Q&A about the ABI alignment rules: [Printing floating point numbers from x86-64 seems to require %rbp to be saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16097173/printing-floating-point-numbers-from-x86-64-seems-to-require-rbp-to-be-saved)

Comment: Related [How to print a single-precision float with printf](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37082784): you can't; `printf` requires its args promoted to `double`, unlike `scanf` which can take a `float*`.