# Why does x86 program segfault without .data section?

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I'm making a basic assembly subtraction function and printing the result to the console. Here's the code I think SHOULD work:
(compiled with `as output.s` , `ld a.out -e _start -o output`)

```
    .bss
output:
    .int

    .text
    .global _start

_start: 

movl $9, %eax
movl %eax, %ebx
movl $8, %eax
subl %eax, %ebx

movl %ebx, (output)

# ASCII for digits is 0x30 greater than digit value
addl    $0x30, output

movl    $2, %edx        # write 2 bytes (need 1 for null?)
movl    $output, %ecx   # output
movl    $1, %ebx        # write to stdin
movl    $4, %eax        # syscall number for write
int $0x80               # invoke syscall

# CR
movl    $2, %edx
movl    $13, (output)
movl    $output, %ecx
movl    $1, %ebx
movl    $4, %eax
int $0x80

# LF
movl    $2, %edx
movl    $10, (output)
movl    $output, %ecx
movl    $1, %ebx
movl    $4, %eax
int $0x80

# exit
movl    $0, %ebx
movl    $1, %eax
int $0x80
```

However, this program segfaults. 
I found that if I add a trivial .data section at the end:

```
    .data   
pingle:
    .int 666
```

it works fine. Why do I need the .data segment? Am I overflowing one of the segments when I write 2 bytes each time? Or is overwriting `output` several times doing this?

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Where does it segfault?  Run your program inside gdb to find out.  Probably having a `.data` section happens to put writeable memory at the location your program is incorrectly trying to read or write, but that's just a guess until you show which instruction is segfaulting and the contents of the registers and symbols used in the addressing mode.

Comment: Finally found the duplicate.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36821123/asm-x64-scanf-printf-double-gas has totally different symptoms, but the cause is the same: Thinking that `.double` with an empty list would reserve space for one double.

Answer (score 3):

**`.int` with an empty list reserves no space**.  Your program doesn't have a BSS.  `.int 0` should work, but using directives that only reserve space is more idiomatic:

Use [`.space 4`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Space.html#Space) in the BSS section to reserve 4 bytes.  Or use `.comm output 4` to reserve 4B in the BSS without using a `.bss` directive first.  `.int 0` should work, too, but using directives that only reserve space is more idiomatic.

See also the [gas manual](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/) and the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki.

IIRC, the BSS can end up being in the same page as the data segment, and memory access checking has page granularity.  This explains why loading/storing from/to `(output)` happens to work, even though it's past the end of the BSS.

---

**An example**

```
 ## nobss.S
.bss
.globl output       # put this symbol 
output: .int

.text
.globl _start
_start:
    mov (output), %eax
```

```
$ gcc -g -nostdlib nobss.S
$ nm -n  ./a.out            # nm -a -n  to also include debug syms, but gas doesn't make debug info automatically (unlike NASM/YASM)
00000000004000d4 T _start
00000000006000db T __bss_start
00000000006000db T _edata
00000000006000db T output
00000000006000db T end_of_bss       # same address as output, proving that .int reserved no space.
00000000006000e0 T _end

$ gdb ./a.out
(gdb) b _start
(gdb) r
 # a.out is now running, but stopped before the first instruction

# Then, in another terminal:
$ less /proc/$(pidof a.out)/maps 
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 09:7e 9527300                            /home/peter/src/SO/a.out
7ffff7ffb000-7ffff7ffd000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7fff000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
7ffffffdd000-7ffffffff000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Note the absence of any anonymous mappings that could be the BSS, or any writable mapping of a.out (data).  Only our program text is mapped.  (With a private mapping, but it's still actually copy-on-write shared.)  See [this answer for what the fields mean](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226283/shared-library-mappings-in-proc-pid-maps).

---

**Terminating 0 bytes in `read` and `write` aren't needed**

```
movl    $2, %edx        # write 2 bytes (need 1 for null?)
```

`read` and `write` system calls take explicit lengths.  You don't need to (and shouldn't) include a terminating zero byte in the length you pass to write().  For example,

```
# You want this
$ strace echo foo > /dev/null
...
write(1, "foo\n", 4)                    = 4
...

# not this:
$ strace printf 'foo\n\0' > /dev/null

...
write(1, "foo\n\0", 5)                  = 5
...
```